# Why CuDNNLSTM vs LSTM have different predictions in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Here's my RNN:

```
def make_cpu_regressor():

    regressor = Sequential()

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(Dense(units=1))

    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
    regressor.save('model-cpu.h5')
    return regressor
```

I created second one with only one difference, I used `CuDNNLSTM` instead of `LSTM`, everything else was the same. NN using `CuDNNLSTM` was trained much faster, but there are significant differences in predictions:

[image: CuDNNLSTM vs LSTM differences in predictions]

Why there's such a difference in predictions?

When I modified `CuDNNLSTM` to units 150 and 200 epochs (blue line) results were much better:

[image: CuDNNLSTM vs CuDNNLSTM vs LSTM differences in predictions]

Edit:
Here's code for CuDNNLSTM version:

```
def make_gpu_regressor():

    regressor = Sequential()
    regressor.add(CuDNNLSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(CuDNNLSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(CuDNNLSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(CuDNNLSTM(units=50))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    regressor.add(Dense(units=1))

    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    regressor.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
    regressor.save('model_gpu.h5')
    return regressor

regressor_gpu = make_gpu_regressor()
regressor_cpu = make_cpu_regressor()

predicted_stock_price_gpu = regressor_gpu.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price_gpu = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price_gpu)
predicted_stock_price_cpu = regressor_cpu.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price_cpu = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price_cpu)
```

Comment: To be clear, you just re-ran your code with CuDNNLSTM  and then compared the results of the two different models?

Comment: @TimH I created function for each model creation. I edited question to enclose more code.

Comment: Have you tried rerunnig the same models to see what is the std? Like if you run CuDNNLSTM, would it give similar results?

Comment: @SaTa, if I understand correctly I did few things to make sure it isn't one-time glitch. I trained these model several times, saved them do disk, loaded them and they still gave different predictions.

Comment: Did you find an explanation for this?

Comment: @adjective_noun I did not